# Not able to use React useState to update a className in a single Array Item

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

UPDATED with Answer below...

I'm trying to understand if the following can be bound separately to each Array Item?

```
const [isDisplayed, setIsDisplayed] = useState(true);
```

I have a List of Items. Each Item has a Details  that I would like to show when an onClick Event is handled. However, whilst it's working, it's displaying the Details  for all Items and not just the Item in question.

Or, do I have to store an isDisplayed attribute for each Item and use useEffect / useReducer?

Ultimately I'm using this and a ternary expression to set a className to either Hide or Show the . But only on one of the Items not All at the same time.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { PropertyContext } from "../../../context/property/propertyContext";

  const PropertyPortfolio = () => {

  const { property, addProperty } = useContext(PropertyContext);

  const [areRoomsDisplayed, setAreRoomsDisplayed] = useState(true);

  const toggleRooms = () => {
    setArePackagesDisplayed(arePackagesDisplayed ? false : true);
    setAreRoomsDisplayed(!areRoomsDisplayed);
  };

  const [arePackagesDisplayed, setArePackagesDisplayed] = useState(false);

  const togglePackages = () => {
    setAreRoomsDisplayed(areRoomsDisplayed ? false : true);
    setArePackagesDisplayed(!arePackagesDisplayed);
  };

  return (
    <div className="propertyList__container">
      <p>You currently have {property.length} properties listed.</p>
      {property.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={item.customerId} id={index} className="portfolioCard__container">
          <div className="portfolioCard__img">
            <img
              src={item.propertyList[0].images[0].url}
              alt="Hotel Awesome"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="portfolioCard__imgs">
            <img
              src={item.propertyList[0].images[0].url}
              alt="Hotel Awesome"
            />
            <img
              src={item.propertyList[0].images[0].url}
              alt="Hotel Awesome"
            />
            <img
              src={item.propertyList[0].images[0].url}
              alt="Hotel Awesome"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="portfolioCard__details">
            <article>
              <h2>Hotel Awesome</h2>
              <h3>Somewhere Awesome</h3>

              <ul>
                <li>
                  <span className="icon">
                    <IconContext.Provider
                      value={{ className: "navBar__icons" }}
                    >
                      <IoIosBed />
                    </IconContext.Provider>
                  </span>
                  <span>50 Rooms</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <span className="icon">
                    <IconContext.Provider
                      value={{ className: "navBar__icons" }}
                    >
                      <IoMdPeople />
                    </IconContext.Provider>
                  </span>
                  <span>5 Room Types</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <span className="icon">
                    <IconContext.Provider
                      value={{ className: "navBar__icons" }}
                    >
                      <FaSwimmer />
                    </IconContext.Provider>
                  </span>
                  <span>10 Facilities</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <span className="icon">
                    <IconContext.Provider
                      value={{ className: "navBar__icons" }}
                    >
                      <FaComments />
                    </IconContext.Provider>
                  </span>
                  <span>248 Reviews</span>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <p className="portfolioCard__details__description">
                Laborum duis Lorem eu deserunt aliqua et sunt in irure ut nisi
                cupidatat enim. Pariatur incididunt magna commodo ut nulla velit
                occaecat officia ex.
              </p>

              <p className="portfolioCard__details__facilities">
                <span>Facilities:&nbsp;</span>Wellness Center, Spa, Swimming
                Pool, Garden, 50 Seat Resturant, Car Park
              </p>

              <div className="portfolioCard__btngroup">
                <button>Reviews</button>
                <button>Details</button>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
          <div className="portfolioCard__price">
            <div className="portfolioCard__btngroup">
             /* MY onClick Events */

              <button onClick={toggleRooms}>Rooms</button>
              <button id={index} onClick={togglePackages}>Packages</button>

             /* MY onClick Event */
            </div>
            <div id={index} className={areRoomsDisplayed ? 'portfolioCard__rooms' : 'portfolioCard-toggle'}>
              <article>
                <div>
                  <IconContext.Provider value={{ className: "navBar__icons" }}>
                    <IoMdPerson />
                  </IconContext.Provider>
                </div>
                <p className="portfolioCard__type">Single</p>
                <p className="portfolioCard__nights">for 3 nights, 2 Adults</p>
                <div>
                  £45.00
                  <p className="portfolioCard__tax">inc Taxes & Charges</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <button>Request</button>
                </div>
              </article>
              <article>
                <div>
                  <IconContext.Provider value={{ className: "navBar__icons" }}>
                    <IoMdPeople />
                  </IconContext.Provider>
                </div>
                <p className="portfolioCard__type">Double</p>
                <p className="portfolioCard__nights">for 3 nights, 2 Adults</p>
                <div>
                  £45.00
                  <p className="portfolioCard__tax">inc Taxes & Charges</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <button>Request</button>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
            <div id={index} className={arePackagesDisplayed ? 'portfolioCard__packages' : 'portfolioCard-toggle'}>
              <article>
                <div>
                  <IconContext.Provider value={{ className: "navBar__icons" }}>
                    <GiHealthPotion />
                  </IconContext.Provider>
                </div>
                <p className="portfolioCard__type">Wellness</p>
                <p className="portfolioCard__nights">2 Days, 2 Adults</p>
                <div>
                  £145.00
                  <p className="portfolioCard__tax">inc Taxes & Charges</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <button>Request</button>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default PropertyPortfolio;
```

The ANSWER...

Thanks to a suggestion by @azium I created a component for the Item itself and passed the Item into the component.

```
{property.map((item, index) => (
    <PropertyItem item={item} index={index} />
))}
```

This allowed me to update the className on a `<div>` within the Item using a ternary.

```
className={areRoomsDisplayed ? 'portfolioCard__rooms' : 'portfolioCard-toggle'}>
```

Comment: use an array? `const [displayedRoomIds, setDisplayedRoomIds] = useState([])` or make the items their own component and handle their own open close state would also work

Comment: @azium Make the Item its own component. That sounds like something I'll try. Let me do that and I'll get back to you. I'm still learning so give me a minute :-)

Comment: @azium Making the Item its own component worked like a dream. Just so I can complete my understanding / learning why is that?

Comment: because that's state for each component as opposed to one state for all components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ANSWER...

Thanks to a suggestion by @azium I created a component for the Item itself and passed the Item into the component.

```
{property.map((item, index) => (
    <PropertyItem item={item} index={index} />
))}
```

This allowed me to update the className on a `<div>` within the Item using a ternary.

```
className={areRoomsDisplayed ? 'portfolioCard__rooms' : 'portfolioCard-toggle'}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each item should have some flag that would allow it to get displayed when clicked on a button.

One of the ways is the following:

1) When `onClick` is clicked, pass an item's `id` to a handler and add/update property on an item, such as `display: true` or `display: false`.

2) Then you'll be able to render each item based on whether `display` is `true`.

Comment: Hi Shohin, thank you for the feedback but I'm not talking about showing / hiding the Item itself. Within the Item is a <div> that I won't to show / hide. I was trying to do this without storing a "display: true" within the Item.